# how do we create a new session on the page if it has timed out

Tags: asp.net, mobile-website, mobile-phones

is there a way to create a new session if it has timed out ? in **mobile appication developing** using asp.net?

getting this error:

`the page requires session state that is no longer available. either the session has expired, the client did not send a valid session cookie, or the session state history size is too small. try increasing the history size or session expiry limit`

this is what i have in my web.config:

```
  <sessionState cookieless="UseCookies" cookieName="Mobile_Session" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true">
    </sessionState>
```

Comment: Technically speaking, the server will automatically generate a new session for the same user once the timeout is reached, because it treats the user as a new visitor. You can test this by setting your session option to use "cookieless sessions" and see how the URL changes over time. I'm guessing you're looking into either preserving the session, or recovering it, and there are some good answers below.

Comment: I cleaned up my answer a little. If you're still having troubles some context may be needed. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session handling is done on the server so if the client sends a request after their current session has timed out the the ASP.Net application will automatically create a new session.

As far as I know once the session has timed out it is not possible to restart it or recover information from it. If you want to prevent a session from ending then you could send a small AJAX request periodically to prevent it (e.g. if you session ends after 20 minutes then send a request every 15 minutes). This request would force the session to stay active.

Comment: is that same apply to mobile application development using asp.net?

Comment: Mobile or not is not important. No difference.

Comment: I haven't used mobile application using asp.net personally but the session handling is the same for the mobile framework as the full one. The basics of session handling (i.e. controlled by the server) is the same for all server side languages included php and other non .Net platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Once the session has expired, there's no way to get it back. You have several options.

- Increase the session timeout in your
  web.config settings (make it last
  longer)
- Periodically cause a postback to
  refresh the session timeout (this is
  usually done in a hidden iframe so the user doesn't know or some kind of popup to give the user the option)
- Redirect the user to a login page or home page and explain to them that their session expired. Its also helpful to save the originally requested url in the newly created session so they have the option to return to the page they were on.

Comment: is that same apply to mobile application development using asp.net?

Comment: Yes. All the server side functionality still applies with ASP.Net, it is just the front-end technology that is different, if you're using jQuery or a different mobile framework on the front end.

Comment: i am getting this error: `the page requires session state that is no longer available. either the session has expired, the client did not send a valid session cookie, or the session state history size is too small. try increasing the history size or session expiry limit`